# Some walls appear too bright while others appear fine

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light

Some walls in my blender project are too bright and others appear just fine. Here is a picture:

[image: One wall appears bright, other appears fine]

[image: Light types]

[image: Light placement and directions]

Link to .blend file removed.

I also forgot to say that I'm using the Blender Internal Rendering Engine.

The .blend will be removed from mediafire when the problem is solved.

Comment: Lights.  Please post an image showing lights, their type, placement and direction.  Materials.  Are the materials being shared between the two surfaces. Large Screen captures make the text entries difficult to read. Consider smaller screen captures.  If you are trying to help others who have a similar problem screen captures persist longer then a (.blend) file that is announced to be scheduled for deletion.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger The materials are being shared between the two surfaces. I posted two more images. One shows the light types, and the other shows the lamps' placement and direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Examine your Lights for position and direction and specular value.  If you use a Sun Lamp and point it you can selectively illuminate a wall.  If you are using specular light direction and viewing angle must be considered.
- Colors.  Make sure the walls share a material.  The materials would have a number 2 or greater if it is shared.
- Examine thes normals of the wall.  Edit Mode. Key N. Mesh Display. Normals Click plane Face Icon.
- More Drastic.  Create archive of file. Delete all lights.  Add back one by one to see if the asymmetry persists. Two antiparallel sunlights should achive symmetrical lighting.

Answer (score 0):

What atomicbezierslinger said: More Drastic. Create archive of file. Delete all lights. Add back one by one to see if the asymmetry persists. Two antiparallel sunlights should achive symmetrical lighting.

My answer:

1. I created archive (well saved another copy of the .blend).
2. I deleted all lamps.
3. I added two suns at the corners of the building. They face diagonally towards the rooms & hallways in the building. Halls are equally lit.
4. I also add 2 more suns that face diagonally up and down, but not left and right. So floors and ceilings are lit, too.

Like the original Point Lamps, the four Sun Lamps were added to a group. Materials in Building A were assinged the light group so they will only be lit by the sun lamps in the building.

Here is an image of the hallway:
[image: Hallways are equally lit]